# Access Spring properties or Profiles in WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies

I configure my `DispatcheServlet` via `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and I am setting up there my session cookie as secured:

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
  ...  

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(true);
  }
}
```

What I want is to set up a session cookie secured or not based on a property in a properties file which is loaded into Spring context via `@PropertySource` annotation in a configuration class. The next option would be make the decision based on active profiles. I understand I can't inject a Spring bean into WebApplicationInitializer, because WebApplicationInitializer is not a Spring bean. Is there a way how to achieve that?